# Why would my Views take longer to load when I'm logged in as a regular user than one I'm logged in as an administrator

Tags: 7, views

I have a Views display that returns a 30 row table of node parameters that is taking about 16 seconds to load when I'm not logged in as either user 1 or one of the users with the administrator role.  When I'm logged in as an administrator the views takes about 2 seconds to load.

What am I doing wrong here?

## **Update**

It's definitely user_access issue... The next question will be, how do I configure the views so that it only checks for the restrictions placed on the views? Here are the SQL side by side

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_year_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_year_value,
   node.type AS node_type,
   node.vid AS node_vid,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_pl_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_pl_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_act_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_act_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_res_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_res_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_sb_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_sb_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_hb_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_hb_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_session_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_session_value,
   node.uid AS node_uid,
   node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format,
   node.status AS node_status
 FROM {node} node 
 LEFT JOIN {content_type_paleghist} node_data_field_lg_year ON node.vid = node_data_field_lg_year.vid
 LEFT JOIN {node_revisions} node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid
 WHERE node.type in ('%s')
   ORDER BY node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_year_value ASC



SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_year_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_year_value,
   node.type AS node_type,
   node.vid AS node_vid,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_pl_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_pl_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_act_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_act_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_res_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_res_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_sb_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_sb_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_hb_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_hb_value,
   node_data_field_lg_year.field_lg_session_value AS node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_session_value,
   node.uid AS node_uid,
   node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format,
   node.status AS node_status
 FROM node node
 LEFT JOIN content_type_paleghist node_data_field_lg_year ON node.vid = node_data_field_lg_year.vid
 LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid
  INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid = node.nid WHERE (na.grant_view >= 1 AND ((na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'all') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only blog') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view blog') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only image') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view image') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only product') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view product') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only memberships') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view memberships') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only donation') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view donation') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only book_sale') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view book_sale') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only cle_class') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view cle_class') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only cle_class_event') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view cle_class_event') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only cle_instructor') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view cle_instructor') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only cle_registrant') OR (na.gid = 3 AND na.realm = 'checkout_item cle_registrant') OR (na.gid = 36 AND na.realm = 'checkout_item cle_registrant') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only cle_roster') OR (na.gid = 3 AND na.realm = 'no_access cle_roster') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only cle_student') OR (na.gid = 3 AND na.realm = 'node_specific cle_student') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only event') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view event') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only jenkdb') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view jenkdb') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only nn') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view nn') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only asklib') OR (na.gid = 3 AND na.realm = 'no_access asklib') OR (na.gid = 1 AND na.realm = 'members_only paleghist') OR (na.gid = 1 AND na.realm = 'all_view paleghist') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only membership_benefits') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view membership_benefits') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only member_directory') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view member_directory') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only page') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view page') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only jlldonate') OR (na.gid = 3 AND na.realm = 'checkout_item jlldonate') OR (na.gid = 36 AND na.realm = 'checkout_item jlldonate') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only rb_case') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view rb_case') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only docdel') OR (na.gid = 3 AND na.realm = 'checkout_item docdel') OR (na.gid = 36 AND na.realm = 'checkout_item docdel') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only book_suggestions') OR (na.gid = 3 AND na.realm = 'no_access book_suggestions') OR (na.gid = 1 AND na.realm = 'members_only document_download') OR (na.gid = 1 AND na.realm = 'no_access document_download') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only form_info_nodes') OR (na.gid = 1 AND na.realm = 'members_only jllfileshare') OR (na.gid = 1 AND na.realm = 'node_specific jllfileshare') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only story') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'all_view story') OR (na.gid = 2 AND na.realm = 'members_only suggestions') OR (na.gid = 3 AND na.realm = 'no_access suggestions'))) AND (  node.type in ('paleghist')
   )ORDER BY node_data_field_lg_year_field_lg_year_value ASC
 LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: By "logged in as an administrator" do you mean logged in as user #1?

Comment: Not just user 1 , also any one logged in user with the 'administrator' role set up through the administrator module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, Views needs to add a join to the node_access table for users without the administer nodes (bypass node access in D7) to check which nodes they are allowed to see.

16 seconds is extremely long, how many nodes are there? Are you using multiple content access modules? Check the number of rows in {node_access}. You an also let MySQL explain what it is doing with the query by executing `EXPLAIN query_here`. It will then show what indexes it is using and so on.

Comment: Thanks.  I have over 300,000 nodes but only running one node_access (at lease I think so).   Though, it's a home cooked module so maybe we're doing something wrong.  We'll be taking a closer look at that module.

Comment: The reason the query is taking so long is basically the DISTINCT keyword, which makes MySQL use disk instead of memory for its tmp table as far as I can tell. :-/ I am seeing this on D6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

See the code for [`user_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_access/6), it doesn't run any queries for UID 1.

Comment: I do believe you are right.  I just checked the sql statements being generated and they are definitely longer for regular users.

Comment: but it does for users of the administer role :) The problem is not user_access() but the node_access system.

Comment: Good point Berdir, I do agree that it's a node access issue.

Comment: I agree with Berdir; that is why I asked if by _administrator_ the OP meant the administrator role, or the user #1.

Comment: Yes, that's why I upvoted berdir's comment and answer. :)